# Can this be done with jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Can i put the value of

```
<input type="text" id="DateofBirth1" />
```

to

```
<%= Html.Hidden("DateOfBirth") %>
```

using jquery in asp.net MVC 1.0?

I am using asp.net Mvc 1.0...and i have to attach a calender with a textbox....but it is not attaching with <%= Html.Hidden("DateOfBirth") %>....so i have tried with this  ...it has done but i cant gat the value of textbox in form collection ? pls help?

Comment: i am not sure what your asking exactly

Answer (score 2):

If you mean "copy the value of the text input to the hidden input", just grab the value of `DateOfBirth1` on change and write it to the hidden field:

```
$('#DateOfBirth1').change(function () {
    $('#DateOfBirth').val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will copy the value instantly, without waiting for the focus to lose (as opposed to the change event)

```
$('#DateOfBirth1').onkeyup(function () {
    $('#DateOfBirth').val(this.val());
});
```

Comment: but at the time of parsing the datetime to string.......... it is saying string is not recognized

Comment: DateTime.Parse(collection["DateofBirth"].ToString());

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= Html.Hidden("DateOfBirth") %>
```

creates an input with id = DateOfBirth, so your Jquery code would be

```
var value = $('#DateofBirth1').val();
$('#DateOfBirth').val(value);
```